# 29 Scoring Nations

Tags: knowledge, geography

The following 29 nations, starting 2022, have scored. Can you explain?

1. United Kingdom  719
2. Germany 415
3. France  308
4. Brazil  293
5. Finland 245
6. Italy   207
7. Australia   130
8. USA 129
9. Austria 118
10. Spain   106
11. Argentina   98
12. New Zealand 71
13. Netherlands 62
14. Belgium 45
15. Sweden  44
16. Canada  39
17. South Africa    36
18. Switzerland 36
19. Colombia    30
20. Mexico  22
21. Monaco  14
22. Poland  12
23. Russia  4
24. Japan   3
25. Thailand    2
26. Rhodesia    1
27. Portugal    1
28. Venezuela   1
29. Denmark 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This scoring table shows the number of

> podium (top three) finishes in total each nation has in Formula One up to the end of 2021.
>
>  Shown in https://www.formula1points.com/nations/nations-podiums on the podiums View.

I stumbled upon the answer after

> ruling out some initial thoughts - Football (UK too high!), Nobel prizes (USA too low). Monaco sparked F1 and searching for 'formula one races won by each country' showed the countries in a very promising order: UK - 307, Germany - 179, Brazil -101, France - 81, Finland - 57. It took some more searches to find the number of podium finishes.

Comment: I am interested in your thought process. Is it possible to add that in your answer?

Comment: @Sid - I had some random wrong thoughts then think it was one small country relatively high up which gave a guess. Though the country is famously related to the knowledge it's not the reason it appears in the table, but probably helped.